# Is there a deterministic observable that has only single eigenvalue?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

Is there an observable in quantum mechanics which has only one eigenvalue and an eigenspace associated with that single eigenvalue? This observable is deterministic in the sense that it gives same measurement value all the time. But the final state would be any of the wave functions living in its eigenspace corresponding to the single eigenvector, with different probabilities.

What would that mean practically, to quantum mechanics?

Comment: The magnitude of the spin ($S^2$) and the mass of a particular particle are certainly single-valued.

Comment: @RobinEkman : not just the magnitude but value should be single. I mean for example only $+1$, not $+1$ or $-1$, meaning the value should be unique, not just magnitude.

Comment: I suppose every operator of that type would be the identity operator (multiplied by a real number).

Comment: @yuggib : not every operator of that type is identity. One more thing is it should preserve norm.

Comment: @RajeshD I don't understand your comment, sorry. The identity operator $Id$ is the operator such that, for any $\psi\in\mathscr{H}$, $Id\psi=\psi$ so it obviously preserves the norm.

Comment: @yuggib if it exists, what would that mean theoretically.

Comment: @yuggib: ok, sorry o thought you are multiplying by a number other than 1. Any way i dont agree identity is the only one of that type. For suppose it exists, what would that mean?

Comment: The identity operator is always supposed to exist in every theoretical formulation of quantum theories I know. My interpretation (but I don't know if everyone agrees) is that "measuring" the identity operator is making the trivial measurement, i.e. no measurement at all (leaving the system unchanged). This is "deterministic" because it would give you a sure output: it would leave the system as it is.

Comment: @yuggib : the system is not unchanged, its final state would be any of the vector in eigen space corresponding to the eigen value 1, in this case(identity), it is the entire projective Hilbert space. of course being in same state has highest probability but other states are also possible with a lesser probability.

Comment: It is usually supposed that an eigenstate is left unchanged after a measurement of the corresponding operator; since all (pure) states are eigenstates for the identity operator, they are left unchanged by the measurement process.

Comment: @yuggib : Should it not transition to one of its eigen space? look at wikipedia page on degenrate enrgy  :

Comment: @yuggib : "In the absence of degeneracy, if a measured value of energy of a quantum system is determined, the corresponding state of the system is assumed to be known, since only one eigenstate corresponds to each energy eigenvalue. However, if the Hamiltonian \hat{H} has a degenerate eigenvalue E_n of degree gn, the eigenstates associated with it form a vector subspace of dimension gn. In such a case, several final states can be possibly associated with the same result E_n, all of which are linear combinations of the gn orthonormal eigenvectors |E_{n,i}\rangle."

Comment: I am talking about state after the measurement is made. Not the mapping of the operator.

Comment: It is usually assumed that given an initial state, the measurement process is such that it gives you as a value one of the eigenvalues, and the resulting state ***is the projection of the original one on the eigensubspace corresponding to the eigenvalue***. Therefore, since the eigensubspace of the identity operator with eigenvalue one is the whole space, and the initial state is in the space, the result of the projection would be trivially the state itself, i.e. the system is left unchanged.

Comment: @yuggib : you are probably right with the "final state is the projection of the state on the eigen space". Makes sense. If you are free,could you take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question and the comments correctly, what is needed is an everywhere defined operator that preserves norms and has only a single point in the spectrum. The first condition forces the operator to be a partial isometry, while the second forces it to be a multiple of the identity. The intersection is then any operator $zI$, where $z$ is a complex number of norm one and $I$ is the identity operator.

Comment: I guess I found a deterministic (single eigenvalue) operator which is not an identity operator (the one that takes $\psi$  and results in $\psi$ itself even after measurement). It takes $\psi$ and results in something else after measurement. I want to show that and test its validity by posting it here, but before that I want to enlive my discovery before it is refuted. So I want to know what are the implications in QM in case such an operator exists.

Comment: It can't possibly be self-adjoint, so it is not an observable.

Answer (score 0):

My contention is that there is an observable other than the identity operator, which is deterministic (meaning single eigenvalue). It is given as follows.

The [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) acts on functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, to give out functions in the same domain, while preserving the norm. Let $f^h$ denote the Hilbert transform of $f$.

Let us stick to $1$-space dimension. Let all the wave functions live in a Hilbert space and be of unit norm.

We define the operator $i\mathcal{H}$ as follows. Let $\psi(x) = \psi_R(x) + i\psi_I(x)$, where $\psi_R, \psi_I$ are real avlued functions. Lets assume $||\psi|| = 1$. The operator $i\mathcal{H}$ is defined as follows.

$$i\mathcal{H}\psi = i(\psi_R^h + i\psi_I^h)$$

Properties of this operator $i\mathcal{H}$,

1. Linear and self-adjoint, and hence an observable.
2. Single eigenvalue $\lambda= 1$. The corresponding eigenspace consists of all the unit norm wave functions of the form $\psi = f+if^h$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $||f|| = 0.5$

**Edit :** After comment from @Phoenix87, it has another eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$ and the corresponding eigen space is wave functions of the form $f-if^h$.

**Note :** $\lambda = 1$ corresponds to particle moving in positive $x$-direction, and $\lambda = -1$ corresponds to particle moving in negative $x$-direction. Wonder what I should name this operator!

3. The final state after the measurement is $$\frac{1}{2}{(\psi_R + \psi_I^h) +/- i\frac{1}{2}(\psi_I - \psi_R^h)}$$
4. Commutes with operators like translations in space and also with the momentum operator.

There may be more properties but these are the ones I could think of.

PS : The properties 1,2,3,4 can be verified using the fact that the Hilbert transform of $f^h = -f$ and few other properties of the Hilbert transform.

Comment: @Phoenix87 : Wish if you could verify this and comment.

Comment: @Qmechanic : Request your help in verification and your valuable comments.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Boundedness, for $p=2$ the Hilbert transform is a contraction, but not necessarily an isometry, i.e. it is not true in general that $\Vert f^h\Vert = \Vert f\Vert$, but just $\Vert f^h\Vert\leq\Vert f\Vert$.

Comment: @Phoenix87 : In the same page, se $H(H(u)) = -u$, which indicates its not a contraction. Hilbert transform is a Fourier multiplier and hence preserves the norm.

Comment: that is ${f^h}^h = -f$, i.e. that the Hilbert transform is an anti-involution

Comment: @Phoenix87 : Thats ok, but it preserves the norm.

Comment: @Phoenix87 : Observe that there is a subtle difference between Hilbert transform and our operator, the hilbert transform acts on real valued functions and , our operator $i\mathcal{H}$ is designed to work on complex wave function, it has different properties from the just Hilbert transform.

Comment: Ah ok, but that follows from $\Vert f\Vert = \Vert {f^h}^h\Vert\leq\Vert f^h\Vert\leq \Vert f\Vert$.

Comment: @Phoenix87 Yep, the author in that wikipedia page at that point was probably interested in mentioning that it is a bounded operator, hence probably would have forgotten to enforce the equality.

Comment: Ok granted this, about point 2: let $H_1$ be the eigenspace of $\lambda=1$. What is the restriction of your operator on the orthogonal complement? Surely it still is a self-adjoint operator on $H_1^\perp$. Since the spectrum of an operator cannot be empty, it must contain something. Either it is still $1$ and you then get the identity, or it is something else hence you don't have a single eigenvalue

Comment: @Phoenix87 : after your comment, I just realized it has another eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$ and the eigenspace of -1 is the orthogonal space, that is functions of the form $f-if^h$.

Comment: @Phoenix87 : edited the answer with $\lambda = -1$. Do you have any comments on the usefulness of this operator.

Comment: I need an upvote for my effort in this answer, despite not being fully right. After all I introduced a new observable!

Comment: It seems that your operator is a unitary self-adjoint operator (it is an invertible self-adjoint isometry on $L^2$). Hence it is not surprising it has only eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$, since it is true for any self-adjoint unitary operator. Anyways, it ***has not*** only one eigenvalue as originally asked in your question. And, by the way, the unitary self-adjoint operators on $L^2$ are infinite.

Comment: @yuggib : Thanks for the comment. Interesting thing is it gives direction of momentum of the particle, without disturbing anything else! The $\lambda = 1$ corresponds to motion in +ve $x$-direction and vice versa.