# A new operator which gives direction of the momentum of the particle in 1-d space, preserving everything else : Need practical applications

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

I have introduced a [new observable](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/158110/540) (unitary self-adjoint operator) which seems to give the direction of the momentum of the particle in 1-dimensional space, without disturbing anything else. We can just get the direction of motion of the particle as along +ve x-direction for eigen value is $\lambda = 1$ and vice versa for $\lambda = -1$. Important thing is that it preserves everything else about quantum system without revealing anything else. Nothing else will collapse.

I'd like to know of any practical applications for this observable/operator in a bigger system.

Comment: The C*-algebra of a 1D system is that of compact operators. It is customary to extend the C*-algebra of a quantum system to its enveloping von Neumann algebra, which in this case is the algebra of bounded operators, but most of the self-adjoint operators in it do not correspond to physically measurable things (they require infinite many procedure to perform a measure, sometimes even uncountably many).

Comment: In what sense is this observable "new"?

Comment: @MarkMitchison : Can we build an efficient quantum coin tosser with this concept? I only woked out the basic math, Its the physicists who can really make it into something physical.

Comment: @RajeshD I am afraid that working out how to do actually do a measurement is the hard bit. Simply writing down the operator doesn't really tell you anything interesting. So although I appreciate the mathematical effort that you have put in, we have learned only that such an observation can be made in principle.

Comment: @MarkMitchison : Ok.

Comment: Can i create a setup where electrons either move in +x-direction or -ve x-direction and there is a magnetic field in the Perpendicular direction. based on the direction of velocity of electrons they get deflected either to right or left and get accumulated on a plate/screen. Can I create a quantum mechanical scale setup and possibnly use this operator in some way?

Comment: That sort of set up would probably constitute a momentum measurement, since the deflection of the electrons should be proportional to their momentum.